# Basic C Programming Storing int to chars

Tags: c++, c

My question is relatively simple but for some reason this bit of simple code perplexes me as to why its not outputting any errors or warnings. Why am I able to store integers in a character array??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char S[256];
    // initialize array
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<256; i++) {
        S[i] = i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to store integers in a char array?

Comment: Wouldn't it require an implicit cast of sorts? the data types do not match up...

Comment: It **is** an implicit cast.

Comment: `int`s are usually bigger than `char`s.  16 or 32 bits vs. 8.

Comment: "Implicit cast", by definition, isn't required. That's what "implicit" means, after all. Your compiler might have non-default compilation options that will enable additional warnings, for cases like these, but since this is perfectly valid code, they are probably not enabled by default.

Comment: Integers _can_ be implicitly cast into a char array, but not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you Sam Varshavchik. For some reason i forgot that chars were much bigger than the integer data type. Also the implicit casting is only valid until you hit the ASCII character 255 otherwise you get an error. Thanks again!!  @SamVarshavchik

Comment: You're welcome. Lesson learned: just because something would be a stupid thing to do, it doesn't mean that you'll get a warning from the compiler, as long as the code meets all requirements of the C++ programming language. Welcome to C++!

Comment: There is no such thing as an implicit cast. What you're looking at is an **implicit conversion**. A cast is something you write in your code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't going to answer this, but every answer that's been posted so far is just close enough to right to be misleading in one way or another.

In C and C++, `char` is a small integer type that occupies an amount of storage that the C and C++ standards agree to call a `byte`--but their `byte` may or may to correspond to what anybody/anything else calls a byte. It is guaranteed to be at least 8 bits, because it must be able to store values from -127 to +127, or else from 0 to 255.

There are two other types named `signed char` and `unsigned char`. A `char` (specified as neither `signed` nor `unsigned`) has the same range as either `signed char` or `unsigned char` (but there's no guarantee/requirement about which, and many compilers support a flag to switch from one to the other). Although it has the same range as one of the other two, a plain `char` is still a separate type from either of the other two (e.g., you can have a function overloaded on all three types).

As noted above, `char` is required to have a range that requires at least 8 bits to store--but it can be larger if an implementation desires (though, in fact, compilers with `char` larger than 8 bits are actually pretty unusual).

When you assign a value like `1` with type integer to a `char`, the value is converted (if possible) to the same value represented as a `char`. If it can't be represented, the conversion will depend on whether a `char` is signed or unsigned. If it's unsigned, then the value will be reduced modulo 2<sup>n</sup>-1, just like other unsigned types. If it's signed, the result isn't guaranteed.

Note that this is a conversion, but *not* a cast. As defined in either C or C++, a *cast* is an explicit notation to cause a conversion. The conversion itself is exactly that--a conversion. Without the explicit notation (e.g., `(char)i` or `static_cast<char>(i)` in C++) what you have is a conversion but *not* a cast.

Answer (score 1):

Characters in C are represented as 8-bit integers. There fore you can treat them as integers and vice versa.

```
// For example:

int a = 3;
char b = 'b';

a = a + b;

printf("%d", b); // prints 98 (ASCII code for 'b')
printf("%d", a); // prints 101 (3 + 98)
```

Comment: A char had to be a minimum of 8 bits to store the managed range.  A char can be larger than 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Basically *char* and *int* data types are integer numbers with 1 byte and 2 bytes respectively.

When the compiler see an attribution from an *int* value to a *char* variable it simply truncate the value in order to fit the size of the *char* data type.

Comment: I would not say an int is 2 bytes.  On many pc's it is 4 bytes.  Even the standard does not say how big an int is but instead mandates a minimum range of values that an int must hold.

Answer (score 1):

A 'char' type designates variables with representation length of 8 bits. Characters are actually "seen" by your program as integers, according to the ASCII table http://www.asciitable.com/.

When you write your for-statement:

```
for(i=0; i<256; i++)
    S[i] = i;
```

the highest value assumed by i and passed to your char* S is 255, which is 0xFF (or binary for 1111 1111), is still lower than the 8 bit limit and can be successfully stored in a char variable.

Comment: As others have answered, chars may actually be longer than 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is just a small `int`. So this is completely legal:

```
int a = 5;
char b = a;
```

The only thing to watch for, really, is if the integer stores a value to large to represent in the char. The actual limits vary by platform.

Answer (score 0):

This assignment is silently converting the integer to a char. This is perfectly legal in C.

```
    S[i] = i;
```

The `char` type is typically 8 bits and signed, and is implied to possibly contain a character. (The number of bits and signedness of the type is technically platform dependent but rarely differs in practice.) So the low 8 bits of the integer will be interpreted as a character.

Comment: I get downcast when people refer to **conversions** as **casts**. Oh, and `char` isn't required to be signed, and the requirement on its size is that it must be **at least** 8 bits. And when it's signed, if the `int` value is too large, the conversion is implementation defined; it is **not** required to take the low 8 bits.